# Meteor deploy (mup) running into errors

Tags: meteor, deployment, bcrypt, mup

```
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
The command '/bin/sh -c cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm' returned a non-zero code: 1
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
rget/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
make: Leaving directory '/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
npm ERR! Invalid version: "https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js/-/core-js-1.2.7.tgz"
```

I am running into an error with bcrypt.

My bcrypt version: ^0.8.7

My meteor version: 1.6.0.1

Comment: This seems to be the source of your problem: `npm ERR! Invalid version: "https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js/-/core-js-1.2.7.tgz"`

Answer (score 0):

mup has some problems with meteor 1.6. Try yamup (yet another mup):

```
npm install -g yamup
cp mup.json yamup.json
yamup deploy
```